# How to conditionally set HTML attributes in JSX using reason-react?

Tags: reactjs, reason, reason-react

I want to render an HTML checkbox whose checked state is controlled by data.

Give a stateless component that receives an `item` type `{ label: string, checked: bool}`,

Like so:

```rust
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("TodoItem");

let make = (~item, _children) => {
  render: _self => {
     <li> <input type_="checkbox" {/*looking for something like this*/ item.checked ? "checked" : "" /* doesn't compile */}/> {ReasonReact.string(item.label)} </li>
  }
}
```

How do I add the presence of the attribute `checked` to the `input` tag based on the `item.checked == true` condition?

Comment: input’s checked prop is just a bool, IIRC. You can do `checked={item.checked}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @wegry said in a comment, it seems to fit your use case better to just pass the value directly since `item.checked` already is a boolean, and `checked` takes a boolean.

But to answer more generally, since JSX attributes are just optional function arguments under the hood, you can use a neat syntactic trick to be able to explicitly pass an `option` to it: Just precede the value with `?`. With your example:

```rust
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("TodoItem");

let make = (~item, _children) => {
  render: _self => {
     <li> <input type_="checkbox" checked=?(item.checked ? Some(true) : None) /> {ReasonReact.string(item.label)} </li>
  }
}
```

Or, to give an example where you already have an option:

```rust
let link = (~url=?, label) => 
  <a href=?url> {ReasonReact.string(label)} </a>
```

This is documented in the section titled [Explicitly Passed Optional](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/function#explicitly-passed-optional) on the Function page in the Reason docs.