# How to pass onClick handler from parent to child components through optional labeled arguments

Tags: reason, optional-arguments, reason-react

I want to pass an event handler down a series of components from parent to child.  Here is a working example:

Index.re

```jsx
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(
  <App myHandler={_evt => Js.log("my handler clicked")} />,
  "root",
);
```

App.re

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent(__MODULE__);

let make = (~myHandler, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: _self => <MyComponent myHandler />,
};
```

MyComponent.re

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent(__MODULE__);

let make = (~myHandler, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: _self =>
    <div onClick=myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>,
}
```

As this code is now, the `myHandler` argument is required at each component usage otherwise we get error:

```jsx
This call is missing an argument of type (~myHandler: ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit)
```

Labeled arguments can be made optional by adding a `=?` in the function declaration like so:

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent(__MODULE__);

let make = (~myHandler=?, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: _self =>
    <div onClick=myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>,
};
```

However this gives a compilation error:

```jsx
  5 │   ...component,
  6 │   render: _self =>
  7 │     <div onClick=myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>,
  8 │ };

  This has type:
    option('a)
  But somewhere wanted:
    ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit
```

I thought that perhaps the compiler might need a hint.  So then I tried explicitly adding that type to the function declaration like this:

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent(__MODULE__);

let make = (~myHandler: ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit=?, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: _self =>
    <div onClick=myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>,
};
```

But then the error flips on me and gives me:

```jsx
  4 │ let make = (~myHandler: ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit=?, _children) => {
  5 │   ...component,
  6 │   render: _self =>

  This pattern matches values of type
    ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit
  but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
    option('a)
```

And now I'm all confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally set HTML attributes in JSX using reason-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844663/how-to-conditionally-set-html-attributes-in-jsx-using-reason-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just to provide a proper answer, since it seems unlikely that this will get closed as a duplicate*

Optional arguments are turned into `option`s on the callee's side of things. Otherwise, how would you represent the absence of the argument. There are no nulls, remember, so nullability must be expressed explicitly.

`myHandler` is therefore an `option(ReactEvent.Mouse.t => unit)`. `onClick` is of course also an optional argument which will be turned into an `option`, but since this is, normally, done automatically we can't just feed it an `option` directly.

Fortunately, someone already thought of this scenario and added a syntactic construct to be able to pass `option`s explicitly as optional arguments. Just add a `?` before the expression passed to the argument, and you should be good:

```jsx
<div onClick=?myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>,
```

Answer (score 1):

So for the optional argument to work you have to handle the optional case itself in the `MyComponent` component.

```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent(__MODULE__);

let make = (~myHandler=?, _children) => {
   ...component,
   render: _self => {
      let myHandler = switch myHandler {
        | None => (_e) => Js.log("default");
        | Some(handler) => handler;
   };
   <div onClick=myHandler> {ReasonReact.string("click me")} </div>
}
```